# Why dont sin and phase shifted cosine overlap?

Tags: matlab

I plotted a sine wave(blue) and a 90 degrees phase shifted cosine wave (red) expecting them to overlap each other.

```
x = 0:0.001:1;

%ploting sine
y = sin(2*pi*x);
plot(x, y);

hold('on');

%ploting cosine 
z = cos(2*pi*x-90);
plot(x, z);
```

[image]

The two graphs do not overlap.
Whats wrong with my assumption ?

Comment: You can also use MATLAB trigonometric functions with argument in degrees: `sind(x)` and `cosd(x-90)`, where $x \in [0, 360]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing degrees and radians.

$$\sin(x)=\cos(x-\pi/2)$$

$\pi/2$ radians corresponds to 90 degrees.